# In P4 command line I only need to get the Description and Files fields

Tags: command-line, perforce

Using CMD why this does not work ?
p4 --field Description="New CL description here" change -o *changelist_number* | p4 change -i

P4 change -o gives me the list of files and an empty description field. What is the best cmd batch command to change the description ? Considering I don't want to replace < enter the description here > with a string finder.

Comment: Be more precise about "does not work".

Comment: Perforce client error:
        p4 -h for usage.
        Invalid option: --field.

Comment: Ok it looks like I need to update to 2016 + version. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the description of a pending changelist, do:

```
p4 --field "Description=NEW DESCRIPTION" change -o CHANGE | p4 change -i
```

Note that you need an up to date p4 client executable (for the `--field` flag) and that this won't work on a submitted changelist since they're protected from editing.

Comment: It will work fine on a submitted changelist if you use `... | p4 change -iu`.

Comment: Only if it's your changelist!  There's also the -f flag if you're the admin.  To learn more: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_change.html

Comment: Well, yes, I assumed we were talking about your own changelists since you can't update somebody else's pending changelist either.

Comment: Is there a way to set the description field to read from a .txt or .tmp file ?

Comment: Not in a single line.  `p4 change -i < file.txt` will read from a file, but it expects the full changelist spec, so you'll need to do `p4 change -o > file.txt` and then insert your description into the `Description` field.  The `--field` flag is just a quick trick to do this same thing in-flight on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for single line description but not multi-line description. Suppose I have a variable `$desc` that contains multiple lines, how will I use it with above command, since this is not working:

```
p4 --field "Description=$desc" change -o CHANGE | p4 change -i
```

Comment: Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and also read [ask] and its linked pages. SO has help available for formatting. See these for more information: "[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/)"
"[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
"[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"